# CustomView (surfaceview) does not match screen dimension (dynamically)

Tags: java, android-studio, game-development, surfaceview

I created a custom SurfaceView, and i am trying to find a solution to match my surfaceview dimension to android screen dimension (dynamically)

**GameSurface:**

```
public class GameSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
```

```
 public GameSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        screenW = metrics.widthPixels;
        screenH = metrics.heightPixels;

        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(getHolder(), this);

        basketball = new Basketball(context, screenW, screenH);
        hoop = new Hoop(context, screenW, screenH);

        background = new Background(context);

        score = 0;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }
```

**MainActivity:**

```
        gameSurface = new GameSurface(this);
        setContentView(gameSurface);
        gameLoopThread = gameSurface.getGameLoopThread();
```

I did try using Displaymetrics, upon testing it on physical device it match the top and left corner but bottom and right corner isnt.